# decodeURIComponent error in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, coffeescript, urlencode

I have a widget that's loaded as an iframe. It has to know some data about the hosting page.
I have several UTF-8 strings obtained from the page. Normally they are some lines of Russian text. The page itself is OK with proper HTML5 doctype and meta charset specification.

Then my code works like that:

```
params = "x1=" + encodeURIComponent(s1) + "&x2=" + encodeURIComponent(s2)
url = "http://mysite.com/iframe.html#" + params

create_iframe(url)
```

where create_iframe is kind of

```
var $if, doc;

$if = $('<iframe>').attr({
  frameborder: 0,
  scrolling: "no",
  allowtransparency: "true"
}).css(css).appendTo($cont);

doc = $if[0].contentWindow.document;

doc.open().write("<head><meta charset=\"UTF-8\"><script>" +
    "var s = \"" + url + "\";" + // <--- here the url is injected into the iframe content
    "function init() { document.location.href = s; }" + 
     "</script></head><body onload=\"init();\">...</body>");

doc.close();
```

Here we use jQuery to create an iframe and then write to its content to make it load our `url`.

Finally when the "http://mysite.com/iframe.html" URL is loaded inside of the iframe, the script inside of it gets the params' values from the hash:

```
var hash_index, loc, param, params, params_array, params_string, tmp, _i, _len;

loc = document.location.href;

hash_index = loc.indexOf('#');

if (hash_index >= 0) {
  params_string = loc.substring(hash_index + 1);
}

params_array = params_string ? params_string.split('&') : [];

params = {};

for (_i = 0, _len = params_array.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
  param = params_array[_i];
  tmp = param.split('=');
  params[tmp[0]] = decodeURIComponent(tmp[1]);
}

return params;
```

This whole thing is working OK in Chrome.

**In IE8 I get an error saying the's invalid encoding when trying to decode the URI**

How should I fix this?

Comment: what language is this?  no parentheses, no semi colon

Comment: Where are the parentheses around the parameter of `decodeURIComponent`?

Comment: these parts are in CoffeeScript (written in the question)

Comment: Then please show what the output of the CoffeeScript compilation is. And can you do a `console.log(tmp[1])`?

Comment: replaced with the compiled JS

Comment: here's a problematic string "%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%AF%D1%82%D0%B0%D1" and it is really malformed. I suspect IE simply truncated too long URL which lead to a string cut between two UTF-8 bytes

Comment: In Chrome I also get the error "URIError: URI malformed". So what do you expect IE 8 to do? It's just malformed.

Comment: See above. Chrome does not truncate the URL. Anyway, I already know the answer to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is - IE is truncating too long URL and it happens between 2 UTF-8 bytes.